# $M \otimes_R N \cong M \otimes_S N$ as $S$-modules?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $S \subseteq R$ be a subring of $R$, sharing a common identity. Moreover, let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. Is it then true that $M \otimes_R N \cong M \otimes_S N$ as $S$-modules?

It feels like I can just define a function $f : M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_S N$ by $f(a \otimes b) = a \otimes b$, which would be bijective and $S$-linear. However, my intuition says that the isomorphism should not hold generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the map $a\otimes b\mapsto a\otimes b$ is well-defined $M\otimes_SN\to M\otimes_RN$ but not the other way. In particular, we have $ra\otimes b=a\otimes rb$ in $M\otimes_RN$ but not $M\otimes_SN$ in general (for $r\in R\setminus S$).

In general, $M\otimes_SN$ is "bigger" because you're quotienting by fewer relations than $M\otimes_RN$.

For example, consider $S=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $R=\mathbb{F}_2[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$. Then as $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces, $R\otimes_SR$ has dimension $4$ whereas $R\otimes_RR$ has dimension $2$, so they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: Hmm, okay! Is there any general class of rings that this is true for though? For example, it seems to be true in the case $R=\mathbb Q$ and $S=\mathbb Z$, since then $(\frac{a}{b}m) \otimes n = (\frac{a}{b}m) \otimes \frac{b}{b}n = ab(\frac{1}{b}m) \otimes \frac{1}{b}n = m \otimes (\frac{a}{b}n)$.

Comment: @Trettman Domains with the same fraction field, for example. Not sure how general we can make it.

Comment: Okay. One more question, to make sure I fully understand: is the map $f: M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_S N$ generally not defined since it need not be the case that $f(ra \otimes b - a \otimes rb)$ is equal to $0$, for $r \in R-S$?

Comment: @Trettman That's a way of putting it.